# Issue when making new label on button press tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
    import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("To Do")
root.geometry("500x750")
root.resizable(False, False)

class App:
    def __init__(self, window):
        #Button font
        self.buttonFont = ("Courier", 13, "normal")
        #Header
        self.header = tk.Label(text = "To Do List\n", font = ("Helvetica", 26, "bold"))
        self.header.grid()
        #Add item button
        self.addButton = tk.Button(text = "Add Item", font = self.buttonFont, bg = "green", command = self.OpenAddItem)
        self.addButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0, )
        #Del item button
        self.delButton = tk.Button(text = "Delete Item", font = self.buttonFont, bg = "red")
        self.delButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, )
        #items frame and stuff
        self.itemsframe = tk.Frame()
        self.itemsframe.grid(row = 2)
        self.item = tk.Label(self.itemsframe, font = ("Helvetica", 11, "normal"))
    def OpenAddItem(self):
        #COnfiguring prompt win
        self.addPromptWin = tk.Toplevel(root)
        self.addPromptWin.title("Prompt")
        self.addPromptWin.geometry("375x100")
        self.addPromptWin.resizable(False,False)
        #Entry label
        self.entryLabel = tk.Label(self.addPromptWin,text = "Enter item name:", font = ("Courier", 11, "normal"))
        self.entryLabel.grid(sticky = tk.E)
        #Adding entry 
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.addPromptWin, font = ("Courier", 11, "normal"))
        self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda e: self.AddItem())
        #Add new item button
        self.addNewItemButton = tk.Button(self.addPromptWin, text = "Add", font = self.buttonFont, bg = "green", command = self.AddItem)
        self.addNewItemButton.grid(row = 1, sticky = tk.W)
        
    def AddItem(self):
        self.entryValue = self.entry.get()
        
        self.item.config(text = f"1.  {self.entryValue}")
        self.item.pack()
        self.addPromptWin.destroy()

app = App(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

---

Hey guys, I'm having an issue with my tkinter gui program.
When i call the addItem function, instead of creating a new label every time, it just replaces the current one. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA when the function is called it creates the label, but when i press it again it just replaces the last one. I want it to add a new label every time the function is called

Comment: Create the label out the function and just call the `config` method on the inside

Comment: @CoolCloud I tried that and I doesn't work

Comment: _"I tried that and I doesn't work "_ what does this mean? any error? there is no reason for it to not work

Comment: @CoolCloud using your method it still creates the label then keeps on replacing it

Comment: Dont give it a `text` argument in the outside

Comment: @CoolCloud I didn't give it a text argument outside of the function, and it behaves the same. Would you like me to post all the code?

Comment: a little bit more could would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a `Label` named `self.item` and you keep overwriting it, expecting it to magically be a new `Label`. The fix is simple ~ don't create `self.item`. Create a list instead and push new `Labels` onto it as they are needed. This sets the stage for your delete method, as well ~ as you can just unpack everything in the cache, delete the desired item and repack whatever is left in the cache. My example is commented where it counts. I didn't write a delete method for you.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("To Do")
root.geometry("500x750")
root.resizable(False, False)

class App:
    def __init__(self, window):
        #Button font
        self.buttonFont = ("Courier", 13, "normal")
        #Header
        self.header = tk.Label(text = "To Do List\n", font = ("Helvetica", 26, "bold"))
        self.header.grid()
        #Add item button
        self.addButton = tk.Button(text = "Add Item", font = self.buttonFont, bg = "green", command = self.OpenAddItem)
        self.addButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0, )
        #Del item button
        self.delButton = tk.Button(text = "Delete Item", font = self.buttonFont, bg = "red")
        self.delButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, )
        #items frame and stuff
        self.itemsframe = tk.Frame()
        self.itemsframe.grid(row = 2)
        
        ''' you just keep overwriting this '''
        #self.item = tk.Label(self.itemsframe, font = ("Helvetica", 11, "normal"))
        
        #start a cache instead
        self.items = []
        
    def OpenAddItem(self):
        #COnfiguring prompt win
        self.addPromptWin = tk.Toplevel(root)
        self.addPromptWin.title("Prompt")
        self.addPromptWin.geometry("375x100")
        self.addPromptWin.resizable(False,False)
        #Entry label
        self.entryLabel = tk.Label(self.addPromptWin,text = "Enter item name:", font = ("Courier", 11, "normal"))
        self.entryLabel.grid(sticky = tk.E)
        #Adding entry 
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.addPromptWin, font = ("Courier", 11, "normal"))
        self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda e: self.AddItem())
        #Add new item button
        self.addNewItemButton = tk.Button(self.addPromptWin, text = "Add", font = self.buttonFont, bg = "green", command = self.AddItem)
        self.addNewItemButton.grid(row = 1, sticky = tk.W)
        
    def AddItem(self):
        self.entryValue = self.entry.get()
        
        '''
            you can keep configuring and repacking this for infinity
            it's not going to change the fact that it's the same label every time
        '''
        #self.item.config(text = f"1.  {self.entryValue}")
        #self.item.pack()
        
        #append a new label to the cache instead
        self.items.append(tk.Label(self.itemsframe, font = ("Helvetica", 11, "normal"), anchor='w'))
        
        #config and pack the last item in the cache
        self.items[-1].config(text = f"{len(self.items)}.  {self.entryValue}",)
        self.items[-1].pack(anchor='w')
        
        self.addPromptWin.destroy()

app = App(root) 
root.mainloop()
```